# Ionic Push Notifications Possibilities?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Ionic app, let's call it Alpha; And I need to use the Push Notifications feature.

The problem is that I need to send from one app to another(both Alpha) an message with texts and information also it suppose to trigger the receiver to show an image stored within the app itself.

I'm having trouble setting up... So I wonder, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it via your server. the sender will call an Server API . and the server will send a push Notification on behalf of the that App. 
There is no other way.

Comment: hmm, but do you know if I can send that type of content?

Comment: Yes you can send a JSON object in push message.on the receiver side, you can trigger a function call which can parse this JSON and decide what to do. you may pass the name of the image in JSON. for example.